# CertPatrol with less annoying UI

Tags: security, firefox

Even with all checkboxes turned off in settings, [Certificate Patrol](http://patrol.psyced.org) often shows top bar or even popup messages when I don't care.

Is there an alternative to CertPatrol with less annoying UI?

Instead of popups or top bar there should be just changed icon colour (showing the popup when I click on it). This way I don't get distracted when doing leisure browsing, still get notified of changing certificates when doing something serious.

Comment: Added answer: Firefox now does this itself. Unfortunately, just probably not for your own bank...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 32 [supports](http://monica-at-mozilla.blogspot.com/2014/08/firefox-32-supports-public-key-pinning.html) Public Key Pinning in a much less annoying way than Certificate Patrol. It does so in a not so intrusive way:

[image]

Unfortunately, only a limited list of websites are supported, see the [Pinning wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SecurityEngineering/Public_Key_Pinning#Implementation_status) for more info.

Comment: And what happens in pinned certificate changed? I want "soft pinning" for multiple sites. Green status - everything OK; Blue status - certificated changed within the same CA because of old is expiring; Yellow status - unexpected certificate change; Red status - something worse, like EV certificate changing to a free certificate. The popup may be shown only if there is a password or authentication cookie present.

Comment: For example, why not have my bank site pinned? This pinning list looks live separating "Jovi" sites from "bovi" ones which may be unprotected from CA abuse... Is there some protocol like "X-Pin-This-Certificate-Please: 6 month" for auto-pinning?

Comment: I totally agree with you. Life is tough.

Comment: @Vi. but most websites change their certificate before expiration, even sometime depending on which server.. Certificate patrols return a lot of unjustified warnings (without even discussing *how* they are reported), Firefox chose the opposite pass - every warning is justified. Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP is coming, I'll will write a more satisfactory answer when that more satisfactory solution (for the web, not only for Firefox) is out.

Comment: Non-intrusive spurious warnings should be OK. One can just ignore them most of the time. But if, for example, while accessing free internet over open Wi-Fi you see some unexpected certificate change when using internet bank (when the certificate usually stable), one can pay additional attention.

Comment: @Vi. that's not what I'm saying; I'm saying Certpatrol is too paranoïd about certificates. If I want security, I want the least possible amount of false warnings.